# Ajuda com Consulta SQL MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso Selecionar Todas mensagens enviadas pelo usuário 1 ao usuário 2  e saber das mensagens envidas do usuario 2 para usuário 1. Não estou conseguindo montar a consulta SQL para a situação Descrita.

Tabela mensagem:

```
IdMsg, IdUserFrom, IdUSerTo, Data, Mensagem
```

Sql que utilizo so lista as mensagen  enviadas dos usuário 1 para o usuário 2. Todas tentativas de saber as mensagens enviadas do usuário 2 para o usuário 1 que tento fazer não funciona
Sendo:

```
$iduserfrom = 1 e IdUserTo = 2
```

SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE IdUserFrom = $iduserfrom AND IdUserTo = $iduserto
```

Comment: o código parece correto, bastando apenas trocar o 1 pelo 2 na segunda consulta. você quer fazer duas consultas mesmo ou listar tudo em uma consulta apenas?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, eis  a questão, quero fazer tudo na mesma consulta, em duas eu consigo em uma não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente assim:

```
SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE (IdUserFrom = $iduserfrom AND IdUserTo = $iduserto) or (IdUserFrom = $iduserto AND IdUserTo = $iduserfrom)
```